# Wordpress slow query when using NOT EXISTS for meta_query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am running a query on a relatively small database (10,000 rows in wp_posts and 100,000 rows in wp_postmeta) but for some reason the query takes around ~5 to 7 seconds to execute.

The args I'm passing into wp_query are;

```
Array(
   [post_type] => post
   [post_status] => publish
   [ignore_sticky_posts] => 0
   [posts_per_page] => 1
   [orderby] => rand
   [meta_key] => 
   [meta_value] => 
   [order] => DESC
   [offset] => 0
   [post__not_in] => Array
       (
       )

   [author__in] => Array
       (
       )

   [tax_query] => Array
       (
           [relation] => AND
           [0] => Array
               (
                   [taxonomy] => category
                   [field] => slug
                   [terms] => Array
                       (
                           [0] => beauty
                       )

                   [operator] => IN
                   [include_children] => 0
               )

       )

   [meta_query] => Array
       (
           [relation] => OR
           [0] => Array
               (
                   [key] => sponsored
                   [value] => 1
                   [compare] => !=
                   [type] => CHAR
               )

           [1] => Array
               (
                   [key] => sponsored
                   [value] => 
                   [compare] => NOT EXISTS
                   [type] => CHAR
               )

       )

)
```

And the SQL query it runs is;

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.id
FROM   wp_posts
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
              ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta
              ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id )
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
              ON ( wp_posts.id = mt1.post_id
                   AND mt1.meta_key = 'sponsored' )
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 3 ) )
       AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'sponsored'
               AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != '1' )
              OR mt1.post_id IS NULL )
       AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
       AND (( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' ))
GROUP  BY wp_posts.id
ORDER  BY Rand()
LIMIT  0, 1
```

I have noticed that the long-query issue resolves itself when I remove this part;

```
Array(
   [key] => sponsored
   [value] => 
   [compare] => NOT EXISTS
   [type] => CHAR
)
```

Which in the SQL query is;

```sql
OR mt1.post_id IS NULL
```

What I am trying to do is look for articles that are marked as `sponsored == 0` or where they're not marked as both sponsored or not-sponsored (sponsored meta_key doesn't exist).

Can someone please point out to me/help me with how I can achieve the same results with a more efficient query/wp_query? Or if you can give me an idea around why `OR mt1.post_id IS NULL` makes the query run for ~5 to 7 seconds whereas without it the query takes ~20 milliseconds?

Comment: Is this plugin installed?  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: @RickJames no I haven't, I'd prefer to figure out the issue first and then implement my own solution instead of using a plugin, but thanks for the input, I'll check the plugin out and see what it does.

Comment: wp_postmeta is very poorly indexed; the plugin fixes that.  However, the `OR` may prevent the use of an improved index.

Answer (score 0):

Rethink how you specify "is sponsored".  You currently have

```
    LEFT JOIN  wp_postmeta  ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id )
    LEFT JOIN  wp_postmeta AS mt1  ON ( wp_posts.id = mt1.post_id
              AND  mt1.meta_key = 'sponsored' 
                          )
    WHERE  ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'sponsored'
                      AND  wp_postmeta.meta_value != '1' )
              OR  mt1.post_id IS NULL 
           )
```

This might be simpler to get rid of those 2 JOINs and change that part of WHERE to

```
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta AS m
                WHERE m.post_id = wp_posts.id
                  AND m.meta_key = 'sponsored'
                  AND m.meta_value = '1' )
```

And, be sure to have [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) . It will add an index that will help that subquery.

I can't be sure, but I think that this is unnecessary (and leads to an extra sort of the intermediate results):

```
    GROUP BY  wp_posts.id
```

`RAND` and `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` both necessitate finding all the rows with term taxonomy 3.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can discuss whether it is unnecessarily looking at *all* posts, not  just the taxonomy 3 posts.  (That may lead to an optimization.)

It's unfortunate that WP does not facilitate putting the sponsored and taxonomy flags in wp_posts.  Then, a composite index would lead to a much faster query.

Comment: I won't be able to do `m.meta_key = 'sponsored' AND m.meta_value = '1'` as in some instances the sponsored meta_key doesn't actually exist

Comment: @PavKR - Fine.  EXISTS will return FALSE.